# Why doesnt vs code close brackets, parantheseses and square brackets when using vue files?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I want to use vs code for .vue file editing, but when writing the first bracket, square bracket, or parantheses, the closing symbol doesnt show up. anyone else has this problem?

Comment: Are you using any extension for Vue?

Answer (score 1):

For VSCode, [Vue.js recommends the vetur extension](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#devtools-extension) for comprehensive language support. This fixed most of my issues when I started out, as it came with things like Syntax highlighting, Snippets, intellisense and many more. This will most likely fix your issue.